# Ruby: Conversion from string to int

Tags: ruby

I've been working on a calculator in Ruby to get a hang of the basics. I take an input from the user in which they tell me the operation, and then I split the string with the space (' ') as the delimiter, and based on which operator the string contains, I carry out that operation. I tried to get multiplication to work first, but I can't get it to work. Everything works fine except the conversion from string to int.

```
puts "Hey? What's your name?"

user =  gets.chomp
user.capitalize!

puts "Operation please"
operation = gets.chomp
operation = operation.split(' ')

answer = 1

operation.each { |var|
    next if var == "*"
    var.to_i
    answer = var*answer
}

puts "The answer is #{answer}, is that right?"
confirm = gets.chomp
```

Comment: Why are you converting `"*"` to an integer?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I'm not, the loop checks if it is " * ", and if it is, it skips the iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var.to_i` itself doesn't mutate the thing it's called on. Methods that do this typically end in a bang (ie. `!`) to denote that, although some don't (see comment).

Use assignment as such: `var = var.to_i`.

Comment: There are many methods that modify their receiver that do not end with a bang ("!"). For example, `a = [1,2,2,3,4]; a.delete(2); a #=> [1, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, you just need to save the result of `to_i` to a variable. As you can see, the operation is not in place, you'll have to store the result:

```
2.0.0-p648 :003 > a = '3'
 => "3"
2.0.0-p648 :004 > a.to_i
 => 3
2.0.0-p648 :005 > a
 => "3"
2.0.0-p648 :006 > b = a.to_i
 => 3
2.0.0-p648 :007 > b
 => 3
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this, i have tried it and it worked!**

```
puts "Hey? What's your name?"

user =  gets.chomp
user.capitalize!

puts "Operation please"
operation = gets.chomp
operation = operation.split(' ')

answer = 1

operation.each do |var|
  next if var == "*"
  answer = (var.to_i * answer)
end

puts "The answer is #{answer}, is that right?"
confirm = gets.chomp
```